# Detect if TLS version prior 1.2 has been disabled on RHEL 7

Tags: ssl, linux

Situation:
I have a RHEL 7 Virtual Machine and I have installed ActiveMQ (v5.16.0) on it (in /opt/...)

Since few days some of my clients cannot connect anymore on the openwire SSL port (61617) with apparently TLS 1.0 protocol.

The error message is:

```
Could not accept connection from tcp://10.10.170.1:45762: Client requested protocol TLSv1 is not enabled or supported in server context (Client requested protocol TLSv1 is not enabled or supported in server context)
```

When I test the port from the server itself with the commands:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:61617 -tls1
openssl s_client -connect localhost:61617 -tls1_1
openssl s_client -connect localhost:61617 -tls1_2
```

... the two first commands does not shows the SSL Certificate but the third one is working properly.

My questions is:

As we did not change anything in the ActiveMQ configuration, I am wondering if some security patches have been passed on the RHEL at the kernel level?
Where I can check on the server if it has been the case?

On the ActiveMQ side, we did not change anything regarding the SSL and our AMQ transport config had never defined the transport.tls:

```
<transportConnector name="openwire+ssl" uri="ssl://0.0.0.0:61617?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
```

Note that the same ActiveMQ configuration is still working on our production servers, which make me think something has been done on the OS level.

I was not sure where to post this question: unix.SE, serverFault or here; feel free to migrate it if you think it rely more on another site.
I focus this question on RHEL but it can be also helpful for others to know for other OS.

Comment: That error wording sounds like Java to me; does ActiveMQ use Java? If so, starting a few months ago standard Java releases (including OpenJDK as used on RH, at least 8 11 16) default-disable TLS 1.0 (which Java calls just TLSv1) and 1.1, although this can be changed in the JVM. (If so this isn't really related to RH or Unix as such.)

Comment: Answering myself, assuming you mean [the Apache one](https://activemq.apache.org/getting-started) yes it's Java.

Comment: This is a good point, the JDK (openJDK) is also managed by the hosting team (not by us managing ActiveMQ) and could be also a point to check. I will compare the versions between prod and non-prod.

Comment: Thanks dave to point me to the right direction, in fact in openJDK 1.8.282 the weakest protocols were still activated but since they patched to 1.8.292, those algorithms are now disabled by default. I published a detailed answer on the cause.

Comment: @moderators: perhaps this question/answer must be migrated to ServerFault as it does not look to be a Unix issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that a recent update of the openjdk (from 1.8.282 to 1.8.292 in our case) disable the TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1 by default.

The change is documented in the [following ticket](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8257122).

Extract of the ticket says:

> Disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1
>
> **Solution**
>
> Add "TLSv1" and "TLSv1.1" to the jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms security property in the java.security configuration file.

You can also see the [RedHat's Release notes](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openjdk/8/pdf/release_notes_for_openjdk_8.0.292/openjdk-8-release_notes_for_openjdk_8.0.292-en-us.pdf)

At Chapter ***3.1.4. Disabled TLS 1.0 and 1.1 versions***

> TLS 1.0 and 1.1 versions of the TLS protocol that are no longer considered secure and are superseded by
> more secure and modern TLS 1.2 and 1.3 versions.
> TLS 1.0 and 1.1 versions are now disabled by default. If you encounter issues, you can re-enable the
> versions (at your own risk) by removing TLSv1 or TLSv1.1 from the jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms
> security property in the java.security configuration file.

This explain why our ActiveMQ suddenly stopped working for the clients still using the deprecated protocols. The best practice would be to migrate those clients instead of re-enabling the weakest protocols.

The "funny" thing is that the service (ActiveMQ) is still working with the latest JDK until you restart the ActiveMQ, hence the date of patching can be different with the date when the client starts to have issues.

Answer (score 0):

As ActiveMQ is the service where clients are connecting, ActiveMQ is the one that explicitly dictates which protols could be enabled for SSL/TLS connection. Change your transport.tls file and add the following contents.

```
<transportConnector name="openwire+ssl" uri="ssl://0.0.0.0:61617?transport.enabledProtocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2&amp;maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
```

This will enable all weakened protocols as well. Keep in mind that TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 are not considered safe and should not be used without caution

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I don't think that would enable the deprecated protocols if they are disabled on Java or OS level.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: If you use the latest version of Java (>1.8.291) the TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are disabled by default whatever you configure at ActiveMQ side, if the JDK disabled it, it does not work.

Comment: Note also that if `transport.enabledProtocols` is not specified, they are all enabled by default at ActiveMQ level.

Answer (score 0):

You can test whether specific TLS was disabled on the server using `curl` command, e.g.

```
curl -vI --tls-max 1.0 https://example.org/
curl -vI --tls-max 1.1 https://example.org/
```

When TLS is disabled, it should produce the error like:

> curl: (35) LibreSSL/3.3.6: error:1404B42E:SSL routines:ST_CONNECT:tlsv1 alert protocol version

Related: [Command prompt to check TLS version required by a host](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74197470/55075).

Comment: This is also interesting but note that curl is for testing https protocol and not for example the ActiveMQ OpenWire 61617. Probably the `openssl` command would also be useful for other protocols.